# Detecting Persons In Seats from Image

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am attempting to build an attendance program which could analyze if someone is sitting in a seat. The seats are fixed making knowing where each seat is easy, but I don't really know where to start to determine if there is someone in the seat. I have tried to do some research but it is all quite complex. I thought that starting with some basic code to highlight contrast would help such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PIL import Image
from pylab import *

im = array(Image.open('images/14.jpg'))

figure('ORIG')

imshow(im)

figure('MOD')

c = copy(im)
c = c[:,:,0]
c = 255 - floor(4 * c**(1/2))
gray()
imshow(c)

show()
```

Which does help:
[image: original]
[image: mod]

Where do I go from here? Are there any good resources for image processing? Is what I have so far a good approach or is there a superior one?

Comment: Asking for off site resources is off topic here. Recommended reading: [Why was my question closed as off topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6487/), but this is an intriguing question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Relevant XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1425/):

[image: Some things are virtually impossible, like checking to see if a photo is of a bird]

On the upside, you might be able to degenerate this task into hand-created bounding boxes for each seat. Take each seat and generate a "base line" from a photo that has no people in any seat under normal expected lighting conditions.

Then when a picture to record attendance is taken - and assuming no smarty pants moves the camera or plays with the lights too much - you can compare each "seat" to the base line. If some measure of difference is sufficiently high (that's not a trivial bit of math), someone must be sitting there. Or maybe someone's shirt looks a bit too much like a seat, or someone sits their coat on the seat, or someone's arm extends too much into the seat.

You can certainly get something to "work", for some arbitrarily low value of work. But for anything else you'll need...well, probably months of hard work and an intensive nose-dive into computer vision. You'll need to expect that the result might be cool (if it ever even works at all), but will very likely be terribly unreliable and unusable outside an academic context.

Reference requests are of course off-topic here, but you might want to consider [Programming Computer Vision with Python](http://programmingcomputervision.com/)...but I'm going to go out on a limb and guess you can't do an `import see_people` and be done in an afternoon...but it's python so I guess I can't say for sure (I'm pretty sure you can't, though).

Answer (score 2):

Posting here because this is too long for a comment, but I'm not sure how good of an answer it is.

I don't mean to be a Debbie Downer, but you haven't really done anything besides make the image gray-scale and increase contrast. Computer vision is a vastly complex topic -- you can't just write a simple Pythons script.

You should start with the fundamentals and work your way up. Be forewarned, computer vision involves a *lot* of math. You're not going to be able to figure out on your own how to recognize people in photographs on your own -- a lot of work has been put into this by very smart people over the years, and we're still not perfect at it.

Of course there are good resources; how could there *not* be at this point? I took a computer vision course in college, and we used *Computer Visions: Algorithms and Applications* by Richard Szeliski. It is a difficult read, but well-written and comprehensive. There is a chapter on human-recognition, with pointers to the literature. You should find an algorithm and try to implement it correctly (this is harder than you would think).

Also, FYI, you may want to switch from Python to Matlab. It has fantastic image processing capabilities and libraries.